# Achievement/Badge System

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently working on a website and I have used PostgreSQL, Express and Node.js technologies to make it.

I want to make an achievement system that is event based. E.g. a user makes a new post and is awarded an achievement/badge for making the first post. I was wondering what the code logic behind this would be? How do I award the user when first post is made? And the next time when user makes a new post again (second post) check if the user already has the achievement/badge for making the first post and just continue without awarding the achievement/badge again?

My database tables

The badges table looks like this:

`id` `name` `description` `icon` `created_at` `updated_at`

user_badges table

| user_id | badge_id | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

users table

`id` `name` `etc...`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoould have one user table that will store user data and with that you should have an column like `totalQaAsked` or `badgeGiven` like this

**user's table**

```
username, userFullName, userLoggedIN, totalQaAsked, badgeGiven
```

At the first time `totalQaAsked` would be `0` so `badgeGiven` would be `false` when user ask his first question then you should have one table that will track question asked by the user and check weather this the first question asked by the user then it will update user's table with `totalQaAsked+1` and `badgeGiven=true`. now you'll have user's data every time you proceed then you can check easily.

Question's table

```
username, question, some more columns
```

#### 2<sup>nd</sup> Method

You can directly query from question with user's id and check how many question asked by the user then you can give badge according to it.